# boolean statement as array template argument

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, conditional-statements, parameter-passing

I have dynamic array template

```
template <class T> class DnmcArray
```

with some typical stuff like size(), insert(), remove(), reverse()...
I want to do something like this:

```
template <class T>
DnmcArray<T>& DnmcArray<T>::filter(SomeGenericBooleanStatement s, T t)
{  
  for (int i = n; i>-1 i--)
  {     
    if (!SomeStatementToFunctionToBooleanCoverter(s, p[i])) *this.remove(i);
    return *this;
  }
```

where SomeGenericBooleanStatement would be something like
`T.sugar() < 4.5` or `!T.IsLemonPie()`

Also it's meant to work with proprietary scripting language which translates into C++ code, so  SomeGenericBooleanStatement would come from it.
Maybe instead of "statement" I should use arguments :
`T.someFunc(), operator, value` ?
In the result I want to be able to write script like
`Pie[].filter(Pie().sugar() < 4.5);`

Comment: Something like this?: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c65d1ed38e18446)

Comment: You may have a look into `std::` library for inspiration. There are a variety of things which work (optionally) with custom predicates. One example: [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) might be worth a look as well.

Comment: If you make your `DnmcArray` look enough like a regular STL container, then instead of writing a member function `filter()`, users of that class could use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) using standard library functions.